# Ubuntu 12.04 suddenly cannot connect to WPA2/WPA Personal protected connection. Windows 7 can

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, wpa2

I have a laptop with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. I have a Cisco E1200 and when I set it up, it created 2 SSIDs. Let's name them:

MyConnection (WPA/WPA2 personal), and
MyConnection-Guest (no authentication, guest password entered via web browser).
I had no problem connecting to MyConnection before, either in Windows 7 and Ubuntu. But now, I can't access MyConnection on Ubuntu. It just says "connecting..." then disconnects after a while. But I'm able to access the internet (on Ubuntu) when I connect to MyConnection-Guest.

MAC filtering is off (even if it's on its MAC address is in the white list). My Ubuntu installation can connect to ANY WiFi connection (WPA/WEP/no auth), except for MyConnection.

Any idea why I'm unable to connect to MyConnection in Ubuntu? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change any settings on the router?

It might be that the operating system has still saved some preferences like another form of encryption or so. If that is the problem you should be able to solve it by deleting and readding the network to your connection list.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that several times and it didn't work. I did not change any settings on the router.